# IfElse or regex

Tags: android, regex, if-statement

Which one of these would be the best way to do this when you have very long IfElse?

```
        if (text.contains("text"))
        {
            // do the thing
        }
        else if (text.contains("foo"))
        {
            // do the thing
        }
        else if (text.contains("bar"))
        {
            // do the thing
        }else ...
```

Or

```
        if (text.contains("text") || text.contains("foo") || ...)
        {
            // do the thing
        }
```

Or maybe

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(text)|(foo)|(bar)|...");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if(matcher.find())
        {
            // do the thing
        }
```

And I mean ONLY when you have to check a lot of these. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually long `If` `else` statements are replaced with `case` statements, but this is not always possible. If I where to recommend, I would go for the second option, option 1 will give you a bunch of `If else if else` statements which do the same thing while for the third case, regular expressions tend to grow pretty large pretty fast.

Again depending on how much `alot` is, it could eventually be better to just throw all your strings in a data structure and iterate over it to see if the element is in it.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally use a set as I think it is easier to read and the `contains` will be efficient in O(1):

```
Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>();
keywords.add("text");
keywords.add("foo");
keywords.add("bar");

if(keywords.contains(text)) {
    //do your thing
}
```

And if you like it compact, you can also write:

```
Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("text", "foo", "bar"));

if(keywords.contains(text)) {
    //do your thing
}
```

And finally, if you always use the same list, you can make keywords `private static final` instead of recreating it each time you run the method.

**EDIT**
Following a comment, it is true that what is above is equivalent to using a condition with `text.equals("xxx")`, not `text.contains("xxx")`. If you really meant to use contains, then you would have to iterate over the set and test each string, but it becomes an O(n) operation:

```
for (String key : keywords) {
    if (text.contains(key)) {
        //do your stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's actually O(log n) because a set is stored internally as a binary tree. A HashTable has amortised efficiency of O(1) though.

Comment: From the javadoc: "This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets" - That should be the case with Strings.

Comment: My bad. I was confusing them with C++ sets, which "are typically implemented as binary search trees".

Comment: But wouldn't this be the opposite of what he wants? if `text` is `"foo1"` `text.contains("foo")` would return true, but `keywords.contains(text)` would be false, because keywords only hold `"foo"`?

Comment: @Jave You are right, what I propose is not equivalent to what he does. Edited my answer.

Comment: I should've used .equals in my example, since the String I am checking with if-else, is just one of those words e.g. "foo" or "bar". With your code I would have to do a long if-else anyway.

Comment: @Urgo "With your code I would have to do a long if-else anyway". What do you mean? There is only one if/else: `if(keywords.contains(text))` returns true if text matches any of the items in the set.

Comment: @assylias I am using an activitygroup that other classes extend. The classes are different tabs and the activitygroup (among other things) checks if it is a certain type of tab and adds options to the OptionsMenu. So, it goes through the certain tabs' tags and checks if the current tab's tag is one of them. That's why I need if-elses.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] storage = {
    "text",
    "foo",
    "bar",
    "more text"
};

for(int i=0; i < storage.length(); i++){
    //Do Something
}
```

Does this help?